# glmmTMB with beta family

Tags: r, distribution, glm, lm, tmb

I am trying to model the photosynthetic response (fvfm) that takes values from 0 to 0.7, I am using the beta distribution since I have zero inflation, and I consider a dispersion model because my values move away from the average as they pass days, but when running this model:

```
beta7<-glmmTMB(fvfm~Temperature*dia+(1|ID), zi=~1, disp=~dia, data=ds, family=beta_family(link="logit"))
```

and this appears :

```
Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 < y < 1
```

I add to all the values of my response variable 0.001, so I no longer have zero inflation and the model works.
This is correct?? or is there any way to run without adding 0.001??
Thank you!!
Regards Fran

Comment: This might defeat the purpose of using zero inflated model... you can check this out https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/355

Answer (score 0):

I think zero-inflated beta might work if your outcome includes 0 - the latest glmmTMB version on CRAN (1.0.0) is able to fit zero-inflated beta-regression.

Else, you might also think about "compressing" your response variable, using the [`normalize()`-function](https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/reference/normalize.html) and setting the `include_bounds` to `FALSE`.

Comment: This was working previously but seems to no longer be the case, as least with version 1.0.2.1